# Pre-compiling issues using the Cloudinary gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloudinary

I'm using Cloudinary in my application and it works like a dream in my dev environment. *However*, when I deploy the app to Heroku and visit a page that has `cl_image_tag`, it gives me the "something went wrong" page.

When I look at the log it gives me this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error ( isn't precompiled)
```

This is the line causing the problems:

```
<%= cl_image_tag(t.image, width: 175, height: 175, crop: :fill, gravity: :faces, border: { color: '#CCC' }) unless t.image.nil? %>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is thrown when the image is nil. Maybe the image attribute of t is nil in this case?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I was checking for that at the end of my `cl_image_tag`. However, I guess using Cloudinary with Carrierwave, I had to use `t.image.url.nil?` instead of just `t.image.nil?`.